# Project one raster into another raster's crs in gdal

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

I've two rasters and would like to project one into coordinate system of another. One raster has an extent in meters and one in lat/long. I would like use gdal to take the raster which has an extent in lat/long and to project it into crs of another raster.

The output of gdalinfo of the first raster is:

`PROJCS["NZGD_2000_New_Zealand_Transverse_Mercator",
    GEOGCS["GCS_NZGD_2000",
        DATUM["New_Zealand_Geodetic_Datum_2000",
            SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137,298.257222101,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6167"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",173],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",1600000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]]]
Origin = (1323824.000000000000000,5190684.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (100.000000000000000,-100.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 1323824.000, 5190684.000) (169d35'25.39"E, 43d23' 9.18"S)
Lower Left  ( 1323824.000, 5004684.000) (169d29'32.65"E, 45d 3'26.70"S)
Upper Right ( 1422924.000, 5190684.000) (170d48'45.84"E, 43d24'56.95"S)
Lower Right ( 1422924.000, 5004684.000) (170d44'59.23"E, 45d 5'20.90"S)
Center      ( 1373374.000, 5097684.000) (170d 9'43.02"E, 44d14'19.75"S)`

And the output of the gdalinfo for the second raster is:
`GEOGCS["NZGD49",
    DATUM["New_Zealand_Geodetic_Datum_1949",
        SPHEROID["International 1924",6378388,297.000000000005,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7022"]],
        TOWGS84[59.47,-5.04,187.44,0.47,-0.1,1.024,-4.5993],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6272"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4272"]]
Origin = (166.474999999999990,-34.424999999999997)
Pixel Size = (0.049382716049383,-0.049423076923077)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 166.4750000, -34.4250000) (166d28'30.00"E, 34d25'30.00"S)
Lower Left  ( 166.4750000, -47.2750000) (166d28'30.00"E, 47d16'30.00"S)
Upper Right ( 178.4750000, -34.4250000) (178d28'30.00"E, 34d25'30.00"S)
Lower Right ( 178.4750000, -47.2750000) (178d28'30.00"E, 47d16'30.00"S)
Center      ( 172.4750000, -40.8500000) (172d28'30.00"E, 40d51' 0.00"S)`

Basically I need to repoject second raster into crs of first and have extent in meters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [GDALWarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html) and assuming bilinear resampling:

```
GDALWarp -s_srs EPSG:4272 -t_srs EPSG:2193 -r bilinear <Your Image> <Output Image>
```

Both [NZGD49](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4272/) and [NZTM2000](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/nzgd2000-new-zealand-transverse-mercator-2000/) are well known coordinate systems, GDAL *should* have no problem converting between them despite the difference in spheroid.